# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, attributes

I had working code on VS 2013 NET4.5. After update (VS 2013, NET 4.5.1) of NuGet packages I got this error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The given filter instance must implement one
>   or more of the following filter interfaces: IAuthorizationFilter,
>   IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter.

I am sure that I implemented **IActionFilter** interface, so how can I get error like this and how can I fix it?

FYI:

```
public class WWWActionFilterAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute, System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            System.Uri Address = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;

            string[] domains = Address.Host.Split('.');

            if (domains.Length == 2)
            {
                System.UriBuilder AddressBuilder = new System.UriBuilder(Address);

                AddressBuilder.Host = string.Format("www.{0}", AddressBuilder.Host);

                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(AddressBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Config

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(System.Web.Mvc.GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new TIKSN.HomeWebsite.Generalization.WWWActionFilterAttribute());
            filters.Add(new TIKSN.HomeWebsite.Globalization.LanguageActionFilterAttribute());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because of *web.config* file. You have to specify exact version of packages there. Look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

**Update**

In Web.config all packages are registered and have their name and version pairs. The actual versions and the versions in the Web.config were not matching.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you changed in Web.config to get this to work?

Comment: In *Web.config* all packages are registered and have their name and version pairs. The actual versions and the versions in the *Web.config* were not matching.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If you edit your original answer where you talk about the Web.config file, I will be able to remove my down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Are we talking about System.Web.Mvc.dll having to have the save version and if so where? If I add this DLL to my domain I can only get up to version 4.0. However I have a version 5.1 in my web API the project with web config file. I really don't understand why I would have to match these versions and why my solution doesn't recognize the highest version if that is why its failing. I believe Visual Studio 2013 Express automatically loaded version 5.1, but I had to get my own for the domain project and that doesn't offer 5.1. One of the worst things about MVC is dependency management.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a HttpFilter (WebAPI filter) to an MVC Global filter. Your filter should be added to HttpFilterCollection

Add this to filterConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterHttpFilters(HttpFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new WWWActionFilterAttribute());
}
```

And this to Global.ascx.cs:

```
FilterConfig.RegisterHttpFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);
```